# Combine Multiple CSV into One Data Frame

Tags: r, csv

I have 1 folder consists of more than 100 csv files, each has different column names (15 column names), and different file names. The example would be as below:

```
[1] "Data/Yahoo_2014.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2015.csv"  
[3] "Data/Yahoo_2016.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2017.csv"  
[5] "Data/Yahoo_2018.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2019.csv"  
[7] "Data/Yahoo_2020.csv"   "Data/Google_2014.csv"
[9] "Data/Google_2015.csv"  "Data/Google_2016.csv"

etc
```

Each csv has different column names. Example for Yahoo Data

```
Date Yahoo
```

for Google

```
Date Google
```

The only thing that is similar is the first column (Date). I want to merge all of this data into one csv file in R so that I can proceed to analyze it. The result should be as below:

```
Date Yahoo Google
1   2014-01-05  75  50
2   2014-01-12  84  6
3   2014-01-19  81  3
4   2014-01-26  82  35
```

I already looked at other questions in StackOverflow but found nothing similar. I came up with this solution but it won't work because they have different column names.

```
data <- read.csv(paste0("Data/","Yahoo_2014.csv"),
                       skip=2, 
                       na.strings="<1")

allFileNames <- list.files("Data")
All <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=0, ncol=3))
names(All) <- c("Date","Yahoo","Google")
for (filename in allFileNames) {
  fullFilename <- paste0("Data/",filename)
  Data <- read.csv(fullFilename,
                         skip=2, 
                         na.strings="<1")
  names(trendsData) <- c("Date","Yahoo","Google")
  All <- rbind(All,Data)
}
```

Comment: Do the columns always refer to the same data, and only those two columns? So the Google and Yahoo columns are always interchangable?

Comment: Instead of `rbind`. we could use `All <- merge(All, Data, by="Date", all =TRUE)`

Comment: basically i have two columns, 1st column is a date, 2nd column is search volume. the 2nd column would be different based on whether it is extracted from google or from yahoo. what i need is to merge the data so that i have separate columns (in this case 16, containing Date and 15 search volume extracted from different sources)

Comment: try that but there's error message `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column` @dario

Comment: You could read a first file and then start the for loop and in each iteration of the loop ``merge` the next file by using `Date` as join variable. And we want to keep all entries from both *sides* of the join, so we set the arguments `all.x =TRUE` and `all.y=TRUE`... that should get you your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

If this is a script that is run frequently one should really come up with an alternative in order to [avoid growing objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf):

Assuming there is always a column named `Date` in the first column and only two columns in total.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
All <- bind_rows(sapply(allFileNames, function(x) {
    Data <- read.csv(filename,
               skip=2, 
               na.strings="<1",
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    Data$site <- gsub(".*[[:punct:]]([A-z]+)_.*", "\\1", filename)
    names(Data) <- c("Date", "values", "site")
    return(Data)
})) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=site,
            values_from=values)

All
```

Older answer:

```
allFileNames <- list.files("Data", full.names = TRUE)
All <- read.csv(allFileNames[1]),
                skip=2, 
                na.strings="<1",
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
All$site <- gsub(".*[[:punct:]]([A-z]+)_.*", "\\1", allFileNames[1)
names(All) <- c("Date", "values", "site")

for (filename in allFileNames[-1]) {
  Data <- read.csv(filename,
                   skip=2, 
                   na.strings="<1",
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  
  Data$site <- gsub(".*[[:punct:]]([A-z]+)_.*", "\\1", filename)
  names(Data) <- c("Date", "values", "site")

  All <- rbind(All, Data)
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
All <- All %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=site,
              values_from=values)
All
```

Comment: Already change date format but still got some missing value (NA) while merging the data. Yahoo data only shows search volume from first file (Yahoo_2014) while Google data only shows search volume from 9th file (Google_2015)

Comment: Is there a `Date` column in *all* of the files? Are they all the same format? Is the `skip=2` argument valid for all of them? I added some print statements that could help figure out whats going on

Comment: Yes for all your questions above. there's something wrong with the paste0 function. Error message : `Error in paste0("  columns: ", names(Data)) : object 'Data' not found`

Comment: hmm something definitely wrong this time. I got too much data than I expected. The date is repetitive for all files. Example: I got 15 rows of 2015-01-04. The number of column also repetitive for all files. Example: I got 6 columns of Yahoo data (Yahoo_2014, Yahoo_2015, etc). What I need is actually 1 column for Yahoo Data search volume (total 15), each with different date extracted from each csv files (2014-01-01, 2015-01-01, etc)

Comment: Maybe it's just the print statements? What about now?

Comment: I know... there was something wrong with my understanding of the question. I think the solution now is more robust and should probably work...

Comment: error while i run the loop function. `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: and i can't understand this line yet : `All$site <- gsub(".*[[:punct:]]([A-z]+)_.*", "\\1", allFileNames[1])`

Comment: Copy paste the code again, best in an empty environment. We are setting the `names` manually, it is not possible that they are not the same... The line you are asking about extracts Yahoo or Google from the filename and stores it in variable. Then we get rid of the original variable name. Later after we combined all files we use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to restore the `Yahoo` and `Google` columns

Comment: got the column and rows names and numbers correct, but there's no value in each cell, instead, it is being replaced by <chr>

Comment: With the data you showed so far this should work. If there are multiple entries for Google on the same day we would need to add an unique ID. But the example data you provided has unique dates... not sure why you would get this result...

Comment: Whats the output of head(All) **before** you call pivot_wider?

Comment: Output after pivot_wider
`Date Google Yahoo
2014-01-05 <chr> <chr>
2014-01-12 <chr> <chr>
2014-01-19 <chr> <chr>`

Comment: this is the output of head(All)

`A tibble: 6 x 15
  Date   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6   v7 v8
  <fct> <lis> <list<chr> <list<> <list> <list<c> <list<> <lis> <list<>
1 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]
2 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]
3 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]
4 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]
5 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]
6 2014~   [1]        [1]     [1]    [1]      [1]     [1]   [1]     [1]`

Comment: Yea, without minimal reproducible example it's going to be impossible for me to see what the problem is... It's getting late. If you add output of `head(All)` (but `All` right *after* the loop and *before* pivot_wider) and the first few lines from the .csv files in an edit to your question (not in a comment, the formatting is horrible) I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: it works now. there's some inconsistency in my data. already fixed it